# How to set target anchor when creating a link

Tags: jointjs

I'm trying to set a specific anchor point when creating a link.  I believe I'm doing everything correctly, but the anchor options are being ignored.  In fact, any options I pass in are being ignored.

My code looks something like this:

```
new joint.shapes.standard.Link().target({id: 'xxx'}, {
    anchor: {
        name: 'center',
        args: { dy: -15 }
    }
});
```

The target id is being correctly handled, but whatever I pass in the second parameter is totally ignored.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: I've gained an insight on the source of the problem:  It's ignoring my opt when I pass in an object, rather than a cell.  So `target(element, opts)` works, but `target({id: element.id}, opts)` ignores the opts.

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting, I worked out that when passing an object with id, rather than parsing a target element, that the opts need to go inside the object with the id.  This is not documented AFAIK.
i.e.

```
.target({id: element.id, opts})
```

In my specific case, I'm passing the following:

```
.target({ id: to.id, anchor: { name: 'center', args: { dy: -15 }}})
```

This seems to work correctly